# Highcharts funnelchart

Tags: c#, asp.net, highcharts

Geting parameter mismatch error when loading my highchart series data form SQL  database.

This is my correct code:

```
public List<string> staging()
    {
        List<string> stages = new List<string>();
        string commandText = "select sc.stagename from currentstage cs inner join stagesconfig sc on cs.stages_id = sc.stages_id group by cs.stages_id,sc.stagename";    
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Data"].ToString()))
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(commandText, conn))
        {
            conn.Open();

            using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    stages.Add(reader.GetValue(0).ToString()); 
                }
            }
        }
        return stages;

    }
public List<int> counter()
    {
        List<int> counts = new List<int>();
        string commandTexter = "select count(cs.stages_id) as StageCount  from currentstage cs inner join stagesconfig sc on cs.stages_id = sc.stages_id group by cs.stages_id,sc.stagename";
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Data"].ToString()))
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(commandTexter, conn))
        {
            conn.Open();

            using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    counts.Add((Int32)reader.GetValue(0));
                }
            }
        }
        return counts;

    }
public void Funnel()
    {

        var a = counter();
        var b = staging();
        Highcharts chart = new Highcharts("chart")
            .InitChart(new Chart { Type = ChartTypes.Funnel, MarginRight = 100, Width = 600, Height = 400 })
            .SetTitle(new DotNet.Highcharts.Options.Title { Text = "Sales funnel", X = -50 })
            .SetPlotOptions(new PlotOptions
            {
                Series = new PlotOptionsSeries
                {
                    DataLabels = new PlotOptionsSeriesDataLabels
                    {
                        Enabled = true,
                        Format = "<b>{point.name}</b> ({point.y:,.0f})",
                        Color = Color.FromName("black")
                    }
                }
            })
            .SetLegend(new Legend { Enabled = false })
            .SetSeries(new Series
            {
                Name = "Stages",

                Data = new Data(new object[]
                {
                    new object[] { b, a},

                }),

            }
            );
        chrtMyChart.Text = chart.ToHtmlString();

    }
```

All my data are been retrieved correctly but creating a new object of data is giving parameter mismatch error.please help

The data should look like this (from comment):

```
Data = new Data(new object[] {
            new object[] {"Website visits", 10000},
            new object[] {"Downloads", 5000},
            new object[] {"Requested price list", 2000},
            new object[] {"Invoice sent", 1000},
            new object[] {"Finalized", 500}
        });
```

Comment: What is the exact error you get (including any inner exceptions) and what line does it happen on? "creating a new object of data" doesn't really help.

Comment: parameter mismatch... Data = new Data(new object[]
                {
                    new object[] { b, a},

                }),

Comment: Data = new Data(new object[]
                    {
                       new object[] { "Website visits", 10000 },
                        new object[] { "Downloads", 5000 },
                       new object[] { "Requested price list", 2000 },
                        new object[] { "Invoice sent", 1000 },
                        new object[] { "Finalized", 500 }
                    }), was working perfectly

Comment: Have you checked that the generated Javascript is what you expect, ie the same as above? Or do you get a runtime error from Highcharts (this is presumably DotNet.Highcharts?)

Comment: Looking closer, there's absolutely no way `new object[] { b, a },` will produce what you want it to: at the very least you'll need to loop through `a` and `b` and assign each value.

Comment: Can you elaborate more

Comment: Sorry, bit busy here.